# "Connection was reset" when including files

Tags: php, server-side-includes

I am having a problem using PHP 5.4 that has me wrapping my brain around it for hours now and it seems quite strange.

I am running a script to load classes based on a structure defined in an array.

The code is as follows:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$directories = array(
    'classes',
    'classes/extendedClasses',
    'controllers'
);

try{
    foreach( $directories as $dir ){
        $dirPath = realpath(__DIR__ . $ds . ".." . $ds . $dir);
        if( !$dirPath ){
            continue;
        }

        //var_dump($dirPath, '<br>');
        $files = scandir($dirPath);

        if( count($files) > 0 ){
            foreach( $files as $file ){
                if( empty($file) || $file == '.' || $file == '..' || strpos($file, '.php') === false ){
                    continue;
                }
                $toInclude = realpath($dirPath . $ds . $file);

                if( file_exists($toInclude) ){
                    include_once($toInclude);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}Catch( Exception $ex ){
    var_dump('Error in including dependencies');
    exit(__METHOD__ . "--" . __LINE__);
}
```

When the code is executed i get a "The connection was reset error".

However, if i remove the line

```
'classes/extendedClasses',
```

From the code, i stop getting the error. Can anyone provide any insight as thus might be happening? Can it be related to the fact that i am trying to include something in a subdirectory? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Any help might be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Luis Dias

Comment: The only time I've ever seen this happen was when using the opcache plugin, if you have it enabled could you try disabling it and try again?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I added php_flag opcache.enable Off to my .htaccess file and got the same error.